# Generic type of (map . filter)

Tags: haskell, filter, types, type-inference, map-function

I don't understand why `map . filter` generic type is `map . filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`.

I know that map and filter types are `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. And also `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`.

So my guess was that `a = (a -> Bool) -> [a]`, `b = [a]` and since the output of filter is not a function, I thought that `map . filter` would return a function that expect a function `(a -> b)`.

I don't understand why the type is a list of lists of `a`, since neither `map` nor `filter` has a list of lists. I also don't understand why it works with just one function since both need one.

Can someone explain how does it work, please?

Comment: Note that `a -> b -> c` means the same as `a -> (b -> c)`.`(a -> b) -> c` is a different type entirely - but your comments imply you see it as equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets use different letters for the types in the functions. That way we won't get confused.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
filter :: (c -> Bool) -> [c] -> [c]
(.) :: (e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
```

So now we consider `map . filter`. Doing the substitution we get the following (`~` is used for type equality):

```
d ~ (c -> Bool)
e ~ ([c] -> [c])   -- Result of 'filter'
e ~ (a -> b)       -- Argument of 'map'
f ~ ([a] -> [b])
```

Notice how we get two types for `e`. By substitution,

```
a ~ b ~ [c]
```

So therefore

```
f ~ ([[c]] -> [[c])
```

And so we can substitute for `d` and `f` in the definition of `(.)` and get

```
(c -> Bool) -> [[c]] -> [[c]]
```

Which is what GHCi was telling us.

What this function actually does is apply the filter to each sublist; the function argument taken by `map` is the filter. So in GHCi,

```
Prelude> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> (map.filter) isDigit ["foo123", "456bar"]
["123","456"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of  `(.)`,

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
 --       f     .     g     :: a -> c    when g :: a->b, f :: b->c
```

means that

```
    g :: a -> b
f     ::      t -> c
--------------------   , b ~ t
f . g :: a ->      c
```

Then following this same schema we get right away that

```
      filter :: (a->Bool) -> ([a] -> [a])
map          ::              ( s  ->  t ) -> [ s ] -> [ t ]
----------------------------------------------------------- 
                           s ~ [a]   t ~ [a]
----------------------------------------------------------- 
map . filter :: (a->Bool) ->                 [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

It makes sense, too. `(map . filter) p = map (filter p)`, so this `map` applies `filter p` to each element of a list (as `map`s do).

Since `p :: a -> Bool`, then `filter p :: [a] -> [a]`.

Since this function is applied to each element of a list, this means that each element of that list has the type `[a]`, and is transformed to another `[a]`.

Thus the whole list was `[[a]]`, and the result of the transformation is also `[[a]]`.